# "mount: Invalid argument" on Android

Tags: android, filesystems

I'm trying to mount an ext4 partition located on my SD card with the following:

```
# mount -t ext4 /dev/block/mmcblk1p2 /data/sdext2
```

But it always returns "Invalid argument". I've verified that ext4 is supported through /proc/filesystems.

Ideas on how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Is it internal sdcard on the device or an external one that you are using?

Comment: Its an internal sd card

Comment: Also I tried ext2 and ext3 which also gave the same error. I've partitioned using multiple software across linux, windows and on the device itself so its probably not that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the SD card I bought from eBay was fake. It was packaged and branded as a 32gb card but the real capacity was 16gb. That's why it failed every time I tried to do 16gb FAT32 and 16gb EXT4. There wasn't any room for the second partition.

If I do 8gb each, it starts working again. Also works if I use a different card.